# Yii storing form data in a session does not seem to be working

Tags: php, session, yii

I want to be able to store form data in a session to be used on other pages, but doesnt seem to be working :

```
//the action controller for the form
$clientInfo = new ClientInfo;
if(isset($_POST['ClientInfo'])) {
    // collects user input data
    $clientInfo->attributes=$_POST['ClientInfo'];
    // validates user input and redirect to previous page if validated
    if($clientInfo->validate()) {
        //store client info in a session varible
        Yii::app()->session['fname'] = $clientInfo->fname;
        Yii::app()->session['lname'] = $clientInfo->lname;
        Yii::app()->session['email'] = $clientInfo->email;
        Yii::app()->session['cellPhone'] = $clientInfo->cellPhone;
        $this->redirect('service'); 
    } 
}
```

Then, in a view I do this, but i get nothing :

```
<div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Overview</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <?php 
        echo Yii::app()->session['fname'];
        echo Yii::app()->session['lname'];
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$loggeduser = array();

$loggeduser['fname']=$clientInfo->fname;
$loggeduser['lname']=$clientInfo->lname;
$loggeduser['email']=$clientInfo->email;
$loggeduser['cellPhone']=$clientInfo->cellPhone;

Yii::app()->session['loggeduser'] = $loggeduser;
```

And

```
 <?php 
            echo Yii::app()->session['loggeduser']['fname'];
            echo Yii::app()->session['loggeduser']['lname'];
    ?>
```

Comment: i get to concept of having to put it in a array, but this is not working either

Comment: this will not work, as you dont have direct access to the session

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian works for me.I'm storing some user data like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing data by this way.

```
$session=new CHttpSession;

$session->open();

$session['fname']=$clientInfo->fname;
$session['lname']=$clientInfo->lname;
$session['email']=$clientInfo->email;
$session['cellPhone']=$clientInfo->cellPhone;
```

To retrieve the values.

```
$session = new CHttpSession;

$session->open();

$fname = $session['fname'];
$lname = $session['lname'];
$email = $session['email'];
$cellPhone = $session['cellPhone'];
```

Thanks

Comment: this isn't working either. Must be some kind of configuration problem, because the solution i use should work just fine according to the documentation

Comment: Search for 'larry ullman using-sessions-with-the-yii-framework' in google and access the very first link, go through that page it might help you understanding and solving the problem exactly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I have to use this

```
Yii::app()->session['fname'] = $_POST['ClientInfo']['fname'];
```

Instead of this

```
Yii::app()->session['fname'] = $clientInfo->fname;
```

Answer (score 0):

or do it like this:

```
Yii::app()->session['client_info'] = $clientInfo->attributes;
```

you will have the entire model attributes stored as a array

and you will use the values as:

```
Yii::app()->session['client_info']['fname']
```